# how to display 36 images per page using thumbnail bootstrap3?

Tags: php, laravel, twitter-bootstrap-3, thumbnails

i want to display 36 images per page using thumbnail, in my case it display 12 and the others not set, like the one indicated in the photo:

**AnnoncesController.php**

```
public function index()
    {
        $categories     = Category::all();
        $annonces       = Annonce::all();
                
        return view('annonces.index')->with([
            'categories'     => $categories,
            'annonces'       => $annonces,
        ]);
    }
```

**index.blade.php**

```
 <div class="row mix-grid thumbnails">
                        @foreach($annonces as $annonce)
                            <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3 mix {{ $annonce->category->slug }} cat_all">
                                <a class="thumbnail-item">
                                    <img src="{{ asset('storage/'.$annonce->image) }}" alt="Nature 1"  />
                                    <div class="thumbnail-info">
                                        <p>Curabitur ut lorem id tellus malesuada tincidunt et eget purus</p>
                                        <button class="btn btn-primary"><span class="fa fa-link"></span></button>
                                        <button class="btn btn-primary"><span class="fa fa-eye"></span></button>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                                <div class="thumbnail-data">
                                    <h5>{{ $annonce->titre }}</h5>
                                    <p>{!! $annonce->description !!} plus details...</p>
                                </div>                                
                            </div>
                        @endforeach
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to paginate items. The simplest is by using the `paginate` method on the [query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries) or an [Eloquent query](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent). The `paginate` method automatically takes care of setting the proper limit and offset based on the current page being viewed by the user. By default, the current `page` is detected by the value of the page query string argument on the HTTP request. This value is automatically detected by Laravel, and is also automatically inserted into links generated by the paginator.

In this example, the only argument passed to the `paginate` method is the number of items you would like displayed "per page". In this case, let's specify that we would like to display `36` items per page:

```
public function index()
{
    $annonces = Annonce::paginate(36);
            
    return view('annonces.index')->with([
        'annonces'       => $annonces,
    ]);
}
```

**Displaying Pagination Results**

When calling the `paginate` method, you will receive an instance of `Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator`. When calling the `simplePaginate` method, you will receive an instance of `Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator`. These objects provide several methods that describe the result set. In addition to these helpers methods, the paginator instances are iterators and may be looped as an array. So, once you have retrieved the results, you may display the results and render the page links using Blade:

```
<div class="container">
    @foreach ($annonces as $annonce)
        {{ $annonce->titre }}
    @endforeach
</div>

{{ $annonces->links() }}
```

The links method will render the `links` to the rest of the pages in the result set. Each of these links will already contain the proper `page` query string variable. Remember, the HTML generated by the `links` method is compatible with the Bootstrap CSS framework.

Comment: 1st position 12 thumbnails images display exactly but images 13 and 14 display incorrectly